# If the $11$ letters $A,B,...,K$ denote an arbitrary permutation of the integers $(1,2,...,11),$ then $(A-1)(B-2)(C-3)...(K-11)$ will be…

Tags: permutations, combinations

**Question:** If the $11$ letters $A,B,...,K$ denote an arbitrary permutation of the integers $(1,2,...,11),$ then $(A-1)(B-2)(C-3)...(K-11)$ will be

a. necessarily zero

b. always odd

c. always even

d. none of these

I am not sure how to proceed. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What's the pattern hidden behind the ellipsis?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Upto that value. Incrementing by one.

Comment: Still don't get it: does it go $(A-1)(B-1)(C-3)(D-3)(E-5)\cdots$ or what?

Comment: Oops that was a typo. It was $(A-1)(B-2)(C-3)...(K-11)$ Updated the post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Always zero is clearly wrong as you could have a derangement.  Note there there are six odd integers among $A,B,\ldots K$, so one factor must be the difference of two odd integers.  That factor will be even, so the product is always even.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? How did you conclude that one factor must be a difference of two odd integers?

Comment: There are eleven factors in the product.  Six of the letters are odd and six of the numbers are odd.  By the pigeonhole principle, two of the odds must be in the same factor.